# Calculating Temperature of boiling water using constant volume gas thermometer

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, gas

Why different gases give slightly different temperature at same pressure in a constant volume gas thermometer?[image]
My book says we should lower the amount of gas in the thermometer to get perfect result [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal gas temperature is derived from a model that assumes the gas in the thermometer behaves as an ideal gas. In reality gases do not behave exactly like ideal gases, and the deviation from the ideal gas model becomes larger with increasing temperature. So the ideal gas temperature is a limiting value that can be found by measuring the derived temperature at a range of pressures, and then extrapolating from these values to find the theoretical temperature at zero pressure.